# I am trying to run a binary search algorithim (Python) in terminal but nothing prints to the terminal

Tags: python, binary-search

```py
def binary_search(item_list,item):

    start = 0
    end = len(item_list) - 1
    found = False

    while (start <= end and not found):
        mid = (start + end) // 2
        if item_list[mid] == item:
            print(item)
            found = True
        else:
            if item_list[mid] < item:
                start = mid + 1
            else:
                end = mid -1
    return found






my_big_array = list(range(10000))
my_big_number = 256

print(my_big_array)

print(binary_search(my_big_array,my_big_number))
```

I try and run this in the terminal and nothing happens at all but when I create a `hello_world.py` file that prints hello world it works fine. Also when I try and run this file in an online python interpter it works just fine

Comment: This code only defines a function, but does not call it. Note that your print statements are *inside* the function body.

Comment: That was an editing error on stackoverflow, in my actual code they are out of it

Comment: There must be an indentation issue. If you're using Pycharm or any other IDE, then use `Ctrl+Alt+i` to manage indent issues.

Comment: ok I will try that thank you

Comment: @MRS_ROBOT , Here is best example to learn binary search in detail with much clear example. [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/]

Comment: This code works when I use an online python interpreter but not in terminal. Does anyone know why that is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the empty lines are the problem.

When you paste that code into an interpreter, your `binary_search` function effectively turns into this:

```py
def binary_search(item_list,item):
    start = 0
    end = len(item_list) - 1
    found = False
```

Because the Python interpreter completes the function definition after the first empty line it encounters. That shorter version of the `binary_search` function doesn't do much and also doesn't return anything.

Try pasting your function definition in the Python interpreter with the empty lines removed.

Comment: Thank you got it running now

Comment: @MRS_ROBOT You're welcome. Then please upvote and accept this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is an indentation problem, your return is in the while loop. Moreover, your first else is also badly indented. Your else must have the same indentation as your if. I tested your code and it works when I correct the indentation.

I hope that that will be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Printing as well as calling the function works for me. You might want to check your indentations as these were messed up in your first post (before the edits):

```
OUT: runfile(...)
OUT: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61...]
OUT: 256
OUT: True
```

Also calling the function does return a result:

```
IN: binary_search([1,2,3,4,5,6],2)
OUT: True
```

However, if the list is not sorted:

```
IN: binary_search([1,4,5,2,5,7],2)
OUT: False
```

So you might want to have a look at that if it is supposed to work in both cases.

Comment: Binary search is supposed to only work with sorted inputs. Otherwise you would have to look through the whole list.

Comment: Well, that depends on what the author is trying to achieve or what their assignment requires. You can sort it beforehand in `O(n log n)` if that is what's required. Not saying it is the most efficient thing to do.